# EditForm in Blazor: EventCallback gives error method group

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I'm duplicating one of my Blazor projects. I have a `Razor Component` called *SimpleAllocation* to display a form like this one

```
// SimpleAllocation.razor
<EditForm Model="Model" OnValidSubmit="@OnValidSubmit">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="q1">Gender</label>
        <select @bind="Model.Gender" class="custom-select rounded-0" id="q1">
            <option value="1">Male</option>
            <option value="2">Female</option>
            <option value="3">Other</option>
        </select>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Model.Gender)" />
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {
    [Parameter] public SimpleRequest Model { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
}
```

In a page I call this component like

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <SimpleAllocation Model="Model" OnValidSubmit="@SubmitForm" />
</div>

@code {
    public SimpleRequest Model { get; set; } = new SimpleRequest();

    private void SubmitForm() { }
}
```

This code raises an error that I have never seen before

> Error CS0428 Cannot convert method group 'SubmitForm' to non-delegate type 'object'. Did you intend to invoke the method?

In my other projects that it is working perfectly. The only thing I did was to update the package

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Blazored.FluentValidation" Version="2.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.10" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication" Version="5.0.10" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.10" PrivateAssets="all" />
  <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Comment: No repro.  Your code is OK (as far as I can see). The error is caused by something else.

Comment: Start by closing VS, delete the .vs folder and rebuild.

Comment: Your code above compiles and does nothing.  On adding a submit button to the component it submits and `SubmitForm` is called.  While the EventCallback should technically return an `EditContext`, it works without.  As Henk says, the problem is in the code you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `EventCallback` parameter has no type, and it's trying to infer it from the method group you supplied (`SubmitForm`), but it can't.

Try having your `EventCallback` generic type parameter be of type `EditContext` (which is what `EditForm` expects for `OnValidSubmit`), and have a parameter of type `EditContext` on your `SubmitForm` method... i.e:

```cs
[Parameter] public EventCallback<EditContext> OnValidSubmit { get; set; }
```

and:

```cs
private void SubmitForm(EditContext context) { }
```

Otherwise, if you are not interested on the parameter at all, you can do:

```
<SimpleAllocation Model="Model" OnValidSubmit="@(_ => SubmitForm())" />
```

Instead of passing `SubmitForm` directly as a method group (that still requires your `EventCallback` to be an `EventCallback<EditContext>` so that razor can figure out what the `_` is)

Comment: Thank you for your post. I tried all of them but I still have the same error or when I use `OnValidSubmit="@(_ => SubmitForm())"` I get _Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'object' because it is not a delegate type_

Comment: @EnricoRossini that sounds like `OnValidSubmit` is not being recognized as an event callback... this is pretty much a shot in the wild, but are you 100% sure you don't have other `SimpleAllocation` component which might not be the one with the `OnValidSubmit` parameter somewhere? Otherwise, make sure you make a clean build (and preferably exit and reopen VS to clean up the caches)

Answer (score 0):

So, after a couple of updates and delete `bin` and `obj` folders, Visual Studio accepted the implementation I showed at the beginning of this post.

Thank you all!